# Wrong number of bind variables error in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to make a statement containing both of these arguments, but I keep getting a "wrong number of bind variables" error. I have posted the code below. Any help is appreciated.

Controller:

```
@open_houses = OpenHouse.upcoming.where('open_houses.start_date >= ?', Date.current, listing_id: @listing.id).order(start_date: :asc)
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Yes, u pass the 2 arguments to `.where()` .. -> `Date.current, listing_id: @listing.id`. It should be 1.

Comment: You can write it: `where('open_houses.start_date >= ? AND listing_id = ?', Date.current, @listing.id)` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write something like this:

```
OpenHouse.
  upcoming.
  where(listing_id: @listing.id).
  where('open_houses.start_date >= ?', Date.current).
  order(start_date: :asm)
```

Because when rails see `where('open_houses.start_date >= ?', Date.current, listing_id: @listing.id)` it expects `where('open_houses.start_date >= ? AND listing_id = :listing_id', Date.current, listing_id: @listing.id)` but I think you not expect that.